Error While Export API from Wso2 APIM using APICTL
i'm trying to export api from wso2 apim using apictl and while exporting the api it prints error in the log
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> apictl login dev -u admin -p admin --insecure
Warning: Using --password in CLI is not secure. Use --password-stdin
Logged into APIM in dev environment
WARNING: credentials are stored as a plain text in C:\Users\youssef.gamal\.wso2apictl.local\keys.json
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> apictl export api --name GenericCso --version 1.0.0 --environment dev --verbose
Executed ImportExportCLI (apictl) on Wed, 03 Jul 2024 19:49:01 EET
[INFO]: Insecure: false
[INFO]: api called
[INFO]: connecting to https://localhost:9943/oauth2/token
[INFO]: ExportAPI: URL: https://localhost:9943/publisher/apis/api/am/publisher/v3/apis/export?name=GenericCso&version=1.0.0&providerName=&preserveStatus=true&format=YAML
[INFO]: ResponseStatus: 200
[INFO]: Extracting C:\Users\YOUSSE~1.GAM\AppData\Local\Temp\apim644902823\GenericCso_1.0.0.zip to C:\Users\YOUSSE~1.GAM\AppData\Local\Temp\apim198201050
apictl: Error creating the final zip archive Reason: Stat : The system cannot find the path specified.
Exit status 1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> apictl get envs
NAME                API MANAGER ENDPOINT     REGISTRATION ENDPOINT   TOKEN ENDPOINT                        PUBLISHER ENDPOINT                      DEVPORTAL ENDPOINT   ADMIN ENDPOINT      MI MANAGEMENT ENDPOINT
dev                 https://localhost:9943                           https://localhost:9943/oauth2/token   https://localhost:9943/publisher/apis                            
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

i'm have tried AI solutions as chat-gpt but not working for me

May I know whether you're trying this in an RDP machine?

Pls try setting up export-directory with r/w permissions and then run the command.

How can i set permission to the directly, cause apitcl tool creates a folder dynamically each run for the command ?

It can be an issue related to the environment setting up. Can you add the environment as below?
apictl add env dev --apim https://localhost:9943 -k

Before adding this you have to remove the existing environment with the name dev.
apictl remove env dev


I'm currently running my  APIM on port 9643 and I tried first to delete the dev env then i runned your command

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> apictl add env dev --apim https://localhost:9643 -k
Default token endpoint 'https://localhost:9643/oauth2/token' is added as the token endpoint
Successfully added environment 'dev'

and when i try to export the api, i found 404 error PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> apictl export api --name GenericCso --version 1.0.0 --environment dev --verbose
Executed ImportExportCLI (apictl) on Sun, 07 Jul 2024 17:17:50 EET
[INFO]: Insecure: false
[INFO]: api called
[INFO]: connecting to https://localhost:9643/oauth2/token
[INFO]: ExportAPI: URL: https://localhost:9643/api/am/publisher/v3/apis/export?name=GenericCso&version=1.0.0&providerName=&preserveStatus=true&format=YAML
[INFO]: ResponseStatus: 404
Error exporting API: 404
